# paragraph indentation does not work

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I am writing my master's thesis on Latex with TeXShop Version 3.88 on macOS Sierra. Anyone could help me as to why none of my paragraphs are indented, please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{Macros_SCF}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{indentfirst}



\includecomment{Graphics}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}      
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{3pt}{-1pt}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}  

\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.1cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.4cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1 cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4.5cm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7cm}

\newlength{\mytocsep}
\setlength{\mytocsep}{1.5em}
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{\mytocsep}}{}
    {\titlerule*[0.5pc]{-}\contentspage}
\newcommand{\myunnumberedsection}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\section*{#1}}


\begin{document}

\setlength\parindent{30pt} 

\section{Introduction}

\begin{flushleft}
\subsection{first subsection}
\end{flushleft}

\begin{flushleft}
This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. 

\indent
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not. 
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not.
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not. 
\end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\raggedright` rather than the `flushleft` environment.  Specify it before setting the value of `\parindent`.

Comment: i want every paragraph to be flushed to the left, except for the first line of every paragraph, which should be indented (not sure if that is what you are asking).

Comment: It should look like this: `...\raggedright
\setlength\parindent{30pt} 
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{first subsection}
This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. 

This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not. 
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not.
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not. 
\end{document}`

Comment: OK so the problem was, I had a bunch of stuff between 

\raggedright
\setlength\parindent{30pt}

and the beginning of the section so it didn't work at all. When putting it right before the section it works with the indents, but now i have to put \noindent before every first paragraph or it will be indented. This is totally fine as long as the other paragraphs are indented. Thank you very much !

Comment: unrelated but I would not use `\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}` use a standard encoding (ansinew is not from ANSI:-)  preferably `[utf8]` or if you want a single byte encoding, use `[latin1]`

Comment: thanks for the tip, but all these packages were put there by my thesis advisor, and i'm afraid to modify them (there must be a reason he put them there and i'm a LaTeX beginner...)

Comment: oops i totally forgot i had used the \usepackage{indentfirst}. Sorry about that!
Weird, but after deleting the indentfirst package i still get the first paragraph of every section indented.

Comment: it's a really bad idea to start with lots of packages, much better to start with none and just add ones you needed, for example `indentfirst` package was only there to force indentation after section headings, which you don't want and the `\titlespacing` commands similarly forced that so the entire answer is basically undoing code that you had copied into the preamble,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

By default latex does not indent after section headings but you had over-ridden that with `\titlespacing` commands, The `\titlespacing*` form keeps the default behaviour of not indenting, so

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{trfsigns}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{comment}
% not availaible\usepackage{Macros_SCF}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}




\includecomment{Graphics}

\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{6pt}{6pt}      
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3pt}{-1pt}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}  

\addtolength{\textwidth}{2.1cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.4cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.1 cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{4.5cm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7cm}

\newlength{\mytocsep}
\setlength{\mytocsep}{1.5em}
\titlecontents{section}[0pt]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{\mytocsep}}{}
    {\titlerule*[0.5pc]{-}\contentspage}
\newcommand{\myunnumberedsection}[1]{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
\section*{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{30pt} 


\begin{document}



\section{Introduction}


\subsection{first subsection}



This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. This is the first paragraph. 


This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not.
This is the second paragraph, which should be indented but is not. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, now it works how I wanted. Have a good day :)